# Angular: Sharing data between components

Tags: angular, components

Let's say I have 3 components, namely `A`, `B`, and `C`. Component `A` has this in its HTML:

```
// a.component.html
<b-component></b-component>
<c-component></c-component>
```

Is there a way that component `A` can send data to each of `B` and `C` and tell them to update from time to time?

BTW, the question is in Angular, not AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this as below. `data_item` from component a will be sent to component b.

a.component.html

```
<b-component [data]="data_item"></b-component>
```

b.component.ts

```
@Input()
data: any
```

Simple demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-to-component?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
this document is very useful.You set an @output from component A and set @input in component B and C . When the value of that varibale change emit an event from A which must handle in  B and C

this is an example code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-interaction-4?file=app%2Fvoter%2Fvoter.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use A's property as an Input parameter for B & C

Answer (score 0):

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Unrelated-Components-Sharing-Data-with-a-Service

Since the components are unrelated, sharing data via `Service` is a good option.